# Count 0 Element in Two list Python

Tags: python

Hi guys i have this problem:
I have a list with number

```
a= [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Every time i found 0 i need to count it and know his position, but when the 0 is consecutive it count as one, for example:

```
 Position start 5, Position end 8, Count 1
    Position start 12, Position end 12, Count 2
    Position start 14, Position end 14, Count 3
    Position start 26, Position end 31, Count 4
```

This can be solved like this

```
a= [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
last_was_0=False
zero_clusters=[]

for i in range(len(a)):
    b=a[i]
    if b==0:
        if last_was_0:
            zero_clusters[-1][-1]+=1
        else:
            zero_clusters.append([i, i])
    last_was_0 = b==0

for i in range(len(zero_clusters)):
    print(f'Position start {zero_clusters[i][0]}, Position end {zero_clusters[i][1]}, Count {i+1}')
```

but if i want to try it on two list? So doing the same thing that i do with one list but having two, and checking if the current index(the same for the two list) if are both 0

```
a= [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

b= [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

How can I achive the result?

I have already tried like this but it gives me as result  only the first iteraction

```
a= [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

b= [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
last_was_0=False
zero_clusters=[]

for i in range(len(a)):
    b=a[i]
    c=b[i]
    if b==0 and c==0:
        if last_was_0:
            zero_clusters[-1][-1]+=1
        else:
            zero_clusters.append([i, i])
    last_was_0 = b==0

for i in range(len(zero_clusters)):
    print(f'Position start {zero_clusters[i][0]}, Position end {zero_clusters[i][1]}, Count {i+1}')
```

Can someone help me achieve the same result of one list but with two??

Comment: you should not assign `b=a[i]`, because it will overwrite `b`, which is a list declared at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the lists together uzing zip, and then use itertools groupby to group consecutive values.

Looping over that and storing the indexes where the key of the group is (0,0) will get you the result you want.

```
from itertools import groupby
a= [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
b= [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

zero_cluster = []
i = 0
for g, d in groupby(zip(a,b)):
    data = list(d)
    if g!=(0,0):
        i+=len(data)
    else:
        zero_cluster.append((i, i+len(data)-1))
        i+=len(data)
        
for i, cluster in enumerate(zero_cluster):
    print(f'Position start {cluster[0]}, Position end {cluster[1]}, Count {i+1}')
```

Output

```
Position start 5, Position end 8, Count 1
Position start 12, Position end 12, Count 2
Position start 14, Position end 14, Count 3
Position start 16, Position end 16, Count 4
Position start 28, Position end 33, Count 5
Position start 36, Position end 36, Count 6
Position start 38, Position end 38, Count 7
Position start 40, Position end 40, Count 8
```

Also it might be helpful to understand what itertools groupby is doing by looking at this:

```
for g, d in groupby(zip(a,b)):
    print(g,list(d))
```

Prints

```
(1, 1) [(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1)]
(0, 0) [(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)]
(1, 1) [(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1)]
(0, 0) [(0, 0)]
(1, 1) [(1, 1)]
(0, 0) [(0, 0)]
(1, 1) [(1, 1)]
(0, 0) [(0, 0)]
(1, 1) [(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1)]
(0, 0) [(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)]
(1, 1) [(1, 1), (1, 1)]
(0, 0) [(0, 0)]
(1, 1) [(1, 1)]
(0, 0) [(0, 0)]
(1, 1) [(1, 1)]
(0, 0) [(0, 0)]
(1, 1) [(1, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`zip()` is your friend when you need to compare elements of a list with it's predecessor or successor.

So you can use zip to get the starting index of each cluster of 1s and 0s.  Then use zip again to combine these indexes into ranges of positions, selecting only the ranges that contain zeros.

```
a= [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

breaks    = [i for i,(n,m) in enumerate(zip(a,a[1:]),1) if n!=m ]
positions = [ (s,e-1) for s,e in zip([0]+breaks,breaks+[len(a)]) if not a[s] ]
count     = sum(e-s+1 for s,e in positions)

print(positions)
[(5, 8), (12, 12), (14, 14), (16, 16), (28, 33), (36, 36), (38, 38), (40, 40)]

print(count)
16
```

For two lists, you can combine them (using zip again) and apply the same solution:

```
x= [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
y= [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

a = [ paired != (0,0) for paired in zip(x,y) ]

breaks    = [i for i,(n,m) in enumerate(zip(a,a[1:]),1) if n!=m ]
positions = [ (s,e-1) for s,e in zip([0]+breaks,breaks+[len(a)]) if not a[s] ]
count     = sum(e-s+1 for s,e in positions)

print(positions)
[(5, 8), (12, 12), (14, 14), (16, 16), (28, 33), (36, 36), (38, 38), (40, 40)]

print(count)
16
```

If you're okay with using a library, this can be somewhat shortened using groupby from itertools:

```
from itertools import groupby

positions = [ (lg[0],lg[-1])
              for bit,g in groupby(range(len(a)),lambda i:a[i]) if not bit
              for lg in [list(g)]]
count     = sum(e-s+1 for s,e in positions)
```

Answer (score 0):

a numpy version

```
a= [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
import numpy as np
def get_clusters(lst):
    arr=np.array(lst)
    diff=arr[:-1]-arr[1:]
    starts = np.where(diff==1)
    ends = np.where(diff==-1)
    indices = np.vstack((starts[0]+1, ends[0])).T
    return indices, diff[diff==1].size
    
print(get_clusters(a))
```

output

```
(array([[ 5,  8],
       [12, 12],
       [14, 14],
       [16, 16],
       [28, 33],
       [36, 36],
       [38, 38],
       [40, 40]]), 8)
```